# Which variable name is proper?

Tags: variables, naming, convention

I want to make a variable that is condiments that the customer wants.

I thought 'condimentCustomerWants' is okay

But I would never see variable name that contains relative pronouns in other's codes.

So I asked to my friends, and he recommended 'customerWantsCondiment', which is sentence.

Hmm.. which name is proper, good, and readable?

Comment: Oh No... `condiment_customer_wants` is proper... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOW you name your variables is entirely up to you, however they should always reflect what the variable is actually supposed to do.

If it is: 'Does the customer want a condiment', you'd want:
CustomerWantsCondiment (true/false value, probably a boolean)

If it is: 'Which condiment does the customer want?', you'd want:
CondimentCustomerWants (for example an int value)

They sound similar, but both have different meanings.
Whatever works best for you, really.

You may also want to adhere to a variable name convention, starting your variable name with a letter, that indicates the type of the variable. That way, you will know the type of a variable at a glance, without having to look for the actual definition.
Please note, that the introducing letter(s) are always lower case.

For example:
    bool  bCustomerWantsCondiment;
    int   iCustomerWantsCondiment;
    char *sCustomerWantsCondiment;
etc.

For more information regarding the hungarian notation, please look here for example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Also, for readability, you should use the 'CamelCase'  convention. That means, each time you begin a new word in the variable name, start it with a capital letter.

Comment: I don't know who voted my post down, but a little hint as to 'why' would be really nice...also, thanks to the person, who voted it up instead.

Comment: it helps me! actually except for hungarian notation.. I heard that it doesn't nees any more.. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MartinSchlagnitweit Thank you very much for the information. I just hate it, when someone -1s my answer and I have no idea why.

Comment: @JonghwanHyeon I'm glad it helps. And even though you don't 'need' the notation, it certainly isn't a bad idea to know, what type a variable is from the name alone.

Answer (score 6):

I'll throw `desiredCondiments` into the mix.

Comment: Oh.. I couldn't think that! I think I should promote my vocabulary things :’(

Answer (score 3):

Depends on everyone's coding style really. i would do

```
requestedCondiment
```

Answer (score 3):

desiredCondiment
preferredCondiment
condimentForCustomer
preferredCondimentForCustomer
wantedCondiment

and so on...